# updatedTransactions not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

App has two in-app products, one works fine in the whole purchasing operation, but another return nothing when finishes purchasing(but completed information from Apple received).

I added `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing` to check the process, I found it's called, but `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased` and even the `updatedTransactions` method not called again when purchasing finished.

The two products are dealt with same codes, have no idea why this happened.

BTW, the product had been purchased before.

Anyone can help? Thanks.

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transaction{
    for(SKPaymentTransaction *tran in transaction){
        switch (tran.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:{
                [self deliverProduct:tran];
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:tran];
            }
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
                NSLog(@"purchasing");
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:{
                [self deliverProduct:tran];
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:tran];
            }
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:{
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:tran];
            }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add some logs to default case and see if you are getting something back there, also are you getting a stateFailed or something else...? default for now will catch `SKPaymentTransactionStateDeferred` case for instance

Comment: @Ladislav not getting any error, the method was not called for the second time. And important is that I get the completed purchasing message from App Store.

Comment: Did you make sure that the delegate did not get deallocated or something like that, it seems almsot imposbile that StoreKit would have an error where delegate for Purchased state would not be called and transaction would complete...

Comment: But another product id works perfectly! I wrote several Apps with Swift, and never met such problem.  And I tested with another sandbox user account, it works in normal in the first purchase, but it failed again when I purchased for the second time. It's weird! By now I have to put a `Restore Purchased` after the every buying action. :-(

Comment: So you do get restore purchased call?

Comment: Purchasing of another product id is ok, and restoring of all ids are ok, it only not work for that product id when purchase for the second time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156763/discussion-between-ladislav-and-jdleung).

Comment: So you are saying you first buy and then you have to buy again just to get the restored purchase and that always works...

Comment: first buy is ok. I have to make the 2nd(3rd, 4th...) buy works in case of users pressing `Buy` again (not pressing restore) after they reinstall the app.

Comment: Are your in-app purchases consumable or non-consumable...non-consumable can be bought just once and if you try to buy them again you will get it restored, consumables like for instance buying coins in a game you can buy multiple times and there is no restore option...

Comment: Both products are non-consumable, and most of products in other apps are also non-consumable, `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased` was called when they were purchased again.